# How to connect to OpenVPN from Chromebook when using tls-crypt?

Tags: tls1.2, openvpn, chromebook

​Hi there!

I'm very Very new to Chromebook and the ONC file, so my apology if it's already asked and answered.

I'm running OpenVPN v2.4.9 Server and everything works just fine form Mac/Linux/Windows using `.ovpn` formatted client configuration file. On the server-side, I'm using  `tls-crypt` ​(as opposed to `tls-auth`) as per the new recommendation and looks like that's where it's failing from the CB, using ONC file.

This is my ***server configuration***:

```
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
ca /etc/openvpn/server/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server/server.crt
cipher AES-256-GCM
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/client
compress lz4-v2
dev tun
dh /etc/openvpn/server/dh2048.pem
explicit-exit-notify 1
ifconfig-pool-persist /etc/openvpn/server/ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
key /etc/openvpn/server/server.key
log         /var/log/openvpn/connection.log
log-append  /var/log/openvpn/connection.log
max-clients 10
ncp-ciphers AES-256-GCM
persist-key
persist-tun
plugin /usr/lib64/openvpn/plugins/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so login
port 1194
proto udp4
push "compress lz4-v2"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0"
remote-cert-eku "TLS Web Client Authentication"
server 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
sndbuf 2097152
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
tls-crypt /etc/openvpn/server/ta.key
tls-version-min 1.2
verb 3
```

And this my ***client ONC config*** :

```
{
  "Type": "UnencryptedConfiguration",
  "Certificates": [
    {
      "GUID": "Bootstrap-Server-CA",
      "Type": "Authority",
      "X509": "MIIGITCCBAmgAw.....MAYsw8ZLPlmJNN/wA=="
    },
    {
      "GUID": "Bootstrap-Root-CA",
      "Type": "Authority",
      "X509": "MIIGDDCCA/SgAf.....TbtcIBMrAiSlsOwHg=="
    },
    {
      "GUID": "Bootstrap-User-Cert",
      "Type": "Client",
      "PKCS12": "MIILvQIBAzCC.....srrOGmHY3h7MPauIlD3"
    }
  ],
  "NetworkConfigurations": [
    {
      "GUID": "BOOTSTRAP_CONN_1",
      "Name": "bootstrap_vpn",
      "Type": "VPN",
      "VPN": {
        "Type": "OpenVPN",
        "Host": "xx.xxx.xx.xxx",
        "OpenVPN": {
          "Auth": "SHA256",
          "Cipher": "AES-256-GCM",
          "ClientCertRef": "Bootstrap-User-Cert",
          "ClientCertType": "Ref",
          "IgnoreDefaultRoute": true,
          "KeyDirection": "1",
          "Port": 1194,
          "Proto": "udp4",
          "RemoteCertEKU": "TLS Web Client Authentication",
          "RemoteCertTLS": "server",
          "UseSystemCAs": true,
          "ServerCARefs": [
            "Bootstrap-Server-CA",
            "Bootstrap-Root-CA",
          ],
          "TLSAuthContents": "-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----\n....\n.....\n-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----\n",
          "UserAuthenticationType": "Password"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It  fails with no such useful message on the client-side (apart from saying: Failed to connect to the network..) but on the server, it's reported as:

```
Wed Sep 23 17:44:15 2020 us=591576 tls-crypt unwrap error: packet authentication failed 
Wed Sep 23 17:44:15 2020 us=591631 TLS Error: tls-crypt unwrapping failed from [AF_INET]xx.xx.xx.xx:64762 
Wed Sep 23 17:44:44 2020 us=359795 tls-crypt unwrap error: packet authentication failed 
Wed Sep 23 17:44:44 2020 us=359858 TLS Error: tls-crypt unwrapping failed from [AF_INET]xx.xx.xx.xx:19733
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong or missing? I'd really appreciate if anyone can put me to the right direction.

-S

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the ONC format does not accept tls-crypt.  If your Chromebook accepts Android apps, you can use the unofficial OpenVPN android app (blinkt.de), which does accept that.